# nginx: index.js" is forbidden (13: Permission denied)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, ssh, digital-ocean

I am doing something wrong configuring my ubuntu server

My browser displays : 403 Forbidden nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

And if i run :

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

i get:
".../root/curlist/index.js" is forbidden (13: Permission denied)..."

This is what i have in sites-enabled:

[image]

What  is the problem?

ps after editing  the sites enabled

if i run:

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

i get :
[image]
However if i run :

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

i get:
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not directly run `index.js` in nginx.

Instead, run `index.js` with node.js in the background, then setup nginx to forward to its listening port.

e.g.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Read an [tutorial of node.js + nginx configuration here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server).

Comment: root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: you have a problematic nginx conf, what does the `systemctl status nginx.service` say?

Comment: the  text was too long for a comment so i have edited my initial post

Comment: `(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` means your `http://localhost:8080` is not reachable. Make sure your node.js service is serving correctly in port 8080, or change the address to the proper port it is serving at. You can check if the node.js process is running correctly by `curl` command first